Differential node not working on other object
I made a differential growth node modifier and it works perfectly on the cube. But i want it to work on different objects, like this hand. But when i add this modifier to the hand, then it doesn't work the same like i did on the cube. the hand splits into 3 parts and then disappears.
What should i do?
[![differential growth working on cube



Show an image of your Geometry nodes and someone might be able to help. As it is, no-one has any idea what you're doing wrong.

Is the scale applied on all objects?

oh thank you so much! I forgot to apply the scale to the hand haha. Now it works

Can you show/explain your "curvature" node here? thanks.

Voxel size is on relation the object scale. Make sure the objects have the same scale to produce the same results.
You can use the apply scale operator. CtrlA
